# Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation

Tags: matlab

```
function r = fun(x, params, type)
    h = @(x) x(1)-x(8);
    x= sym('x',[1,8]);

    gamma = 16;

    if type == 'linear'
        r = gamma*h(x);
    elseif type == 'sin'
        r = gamma*sin(h(x));
    end
    
end
```

When I run this function for type 'sin' I always get this error

```
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in fun (line 7)
    if type == 'linear'
```

How to fix this?

I just one to pass type and depending on that create my ouput, I though string could be okay, but it doesn't work.

I want to multiply my function handle with gamma in case of linear and multiply and take sin in case of sine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may mean

```
if strcmp(type,'linear')
```

`type` is a char array, and matlab does not support that type of direct array to array comparison for text. It tries to compare each letter with each other, but if `length(type)` is not the same as `length('linear')` it errors.